# Jquery only works if that's the only element on the page

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a bunch of input fields inside a form which should only show up if a button is clicked. If it's only the input fields, the jquery script itself on the page (included in the index file which contains only the design and the head element) it works perfectly. But when it's inside the form which contains other form elements (text, checkbox etc.) and an AJAX script it doesn't work.

Here's the script:

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.show').click(function() {
            $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the div element (I have fifteen but I thought 3 would be enough)

```
<tr><td class="cimek"><input type="text" name="1ros1"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="elem"><input type="text" name="1rossi1">Ft</td></tr>
<tr><td class="elem"><a href="#" class="show">Új</a></td></tr>
<div class="ujDiv">
    <tr><td class="cimek"><input type="text" name="1ros2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="elem"><input type="text" name="1rossi2">Ft</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="elem"><a href="#" class="show">Új</a></td></tr>

    <div class="ujDiv">
        <tr><td class="cimek"><input type="text" name="1ros3"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="elem"><input type="text" name="1rossi3">Ft</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="elem"><a href="#" class="show">Új</a></td></tr>

        <div class="ujDiv">
            <tr><td class="cimek"><input type="text" name="1ros4"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="elem"><input type="text" name="1rossi4">Ft</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="elem"><a href="#" class="show">Új</a></td></tr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also put a `display:none;` on the `.ujDiv` class because that was the only way I could hide it when it first loads.

So any ideas how can I hide them when there are other form elements in the file?

Comment: Please write question properly as understandable.

Comment: The HTML is invalid. You can't use divs to group table rows.

Comment: Plus u are closing Divs at the end.

Comment: When the script and the divs are the only ones in the file it works perfectly (the are hidden until I click on the "Új" link) but when there are other form elements around it every div that should be hidden until the displayed as if the script isn't there (not to mention that the .elem and .cimek classes aren't working either)

Answer (score 0):

try the above snippet, but i think you will have to adjust it because there is apossible a table tag outside the code you gave us:

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.show').click(function() {
                $(this).parents().eq(3).next('div').slideToggle();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ujDiv">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="cimek"><input type="text" name="1ros1"></td>
                <td class="elem"><input type="text" name="1rossi1">1</td>
                <td class="elem"><a href="#" class="show">2</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="ujDiv">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="cimek"><input type="text" name="1ros2"></td>
                    <td class="elem"><input type="text" name="1rossi2">3</td>
                    <td class="elem"><a href="#" class="show">4</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="ujDiv">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="cimek"><input type="text" name="1ros3"></td>
                    <td class="elem"><input type="text" name="1rossi3">5</td>
                    <td class="elem"><a href="#" class="show">6</a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            <div class="ujDiv">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cimek"><input type="text" name="1ros4"></td>
                        <td class="elem"><input type="text" name="1rossi4">7</td>
                        <td class="elem"><a href="#" class="show">8</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```